# Apache Beam retryable errors appears to not work for certain errors

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using big query io to write data to tables using the dynamic destinations api. In my big query transform i set `InsertRetryPolicy` to `never()`

For certain classes of big query errors, the ones I've noticed are schema errors the Policy is used in the BigQueryServicesImpl, from lines 751 to 771.

However certain classes errors throw an exception in the underlying bigquery client, this exception is not caught and line 751 where you do

```
List<TableDataInsertAllResponse.InsertErrors> errors = futures.get(i).get()
```

The exception bubbles up and doesn't go through the logic to ask the policy if it should retry. As a result the bundle fails and since its a streaming job it will retry this bundle forever stalling my pipeline.

Errors that throw exceptions that i have observed are:

```
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not found: Table account:dataset.paymentfraudresultsv1_uk_2018",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  }


{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The destination table's partition whatever_uk_2017$20171020 is outside the allowed bounds. You can only stream to partitions within 31 days in the past and 16 days in the future relative to the current date.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  }
```

I'm not sure why some errors are represented as a data class and some throw exceptions in the underlying client but its having this unfortunate effect.